# Fast way to store data and extract them

Tags: php, database, performance, data-storage

I want to find a way (in PHP) to store temporary data in quickly, to be able to extract them quickly also.

For now, i'm using a mysql database, but the response time is too long.

Here's what i'm thinking right now... I thought that the fastest way to store data was to put it in an "global" array and use it to insert and extract data. The problem was that i was not able to find a way to create a "global" variable that could be use by all client or session.

My second guess is that, probably a JSON or XML file would be faster than the DB. But i'm not shure that it would be fast enough since the data as to be written on the HDD also.

So ideally would be to use a "global" variable that could be use by all client. So if you know a way i could do this or if you have any quick way to sotre data, i'm listening!

Thank you

Comment: Response times for well kept RDMS is in fractions of seconds.  If what your doing is longer than this its likely you have a RDMS that isn't well kept or your network configuration is causing unneeded delays,.  (Just like the word unneeded in the above)

Comment: How do you know that the database is the bottleneck? Have you profiled any of your code? Analyzed your SQL queries? Even if the DB is the bottleneck, have you made sure that your tables are properly indexed? etc.

Comment: As for the fact that the data is temporary: what is the expected lifespan of the data? How much of it is there? Does it need to be updated or only read? How much at a time? By how many threads/processes/clients? I hope my questions illustrate the futility of answering your question as posed. You need to provide significantly more information if we are to constructively respond (unlike Daniel's answer below, which is nothing but a shot in the dark).

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a [Real-time Database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_database) like [this](http://www.mimer.com/Products/MimerSQLRealtime/MimerSQLRealTimeBenchmark.aspx).